# How to adapt scrolling jQuery listeners to CSS media queries? (Javascript/ jQuery / Bootstrap)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm new to all this; so I've been trying for the past day to get the jQuery to function. I have a navigation bar(nav bar) that changes background-color/color due to scrolling position, this is done through jQuery.  I have it working effectively on desktop width (1350px) but trying to juggle both the media queries and the jQuery listeners seems impossible. I've applied eveything I've found, and tried it all twice but to no avail.

**HTML**

The HTML is pretty a basic Bootstrap navbar, the navbar just changes due to the jQuery (scroll position)

```
</head>
 <body>
  <nav class="navbar sticky-top navbar-expand-sm">
        <a class="navbar-title" href="#aboutUs-box">counterCarbon</a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"><i class="fas fa-bars"></i><span>
        </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
            <ul class="navbar-nav align-items-end">
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link active" href="#navLink1">Emissions</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#navLink2">Comparisons</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#navLink3">Partners</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>
```

**CSS**

The only interesting part of the CSS would be the visible/hidden changes made, I imagine.

```
.visible {
    visibility: visible;
    opacity: 1;
    transition: opacity .35s linear, color .5s; 
}
.hidden {
    visibility: hidden;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: visibility .50s, opacity .50s linear, color .5s;
}
```

**jQuery**

The changes are all implemented with the jQuery, the navbar should change the excat same way just at different scrolling positions depending on the different width/device used. Crucially I can't get the program to recognise three separate ($(window).width()) blocks (ie, all three sections) recoginsing one is easy. But it seems to get confused with two and three is completely impossible.

````
$(document).ready(function(){ 
            var scroll_pos = 0;

            $(document).scroll(function() { 
                scroll_pos = $(this).scrollTop(); 


                {if(($(window).width() >= 1350 && scroll_pos > 50)) {
                    $("nav").removeClass("visible").addClass("hidden");
                    $("nav a").removeClass("visible").addClass("hidden");
                    $("nav span").removeClass("visible").addClass("hidden");

                } 
                if(($(window).width() >= 1350 && scroll_pos > 690)) {
                    $("nav").removeClass("hidden").addClass("visible");
                    $("nav a").removeClass("hidden").addClass("visible");
                    $("nav span").removeClass("hidden").addClass("visible");
                    $("nav").css('background-color', '#fafafa');

                    $("nav a").css('color', '#404040');
                    $('nav span').css('color','#404040');
                }
                else {
                    $("nav").css('background-color', 'transparent');
                    $("nav a").css('color', '#fafafa');
                    $("nav span").css('color', '#fafafa');
                }
                if(($(window).width() >= 1350 && scroll_pos > 1270)) {
                    $("nav a").css('color', '#33adff');
                    $("nav span").css('color', '#33adff');
                }
                if(($(window).width() >= 1350 && scroll_pos > 1290)) {
                    $("nav").css('background-color', '#fafafa');
                }

                if(($(window).width() >= 1350 && scroll_pos < 50)) {
                    $("nav").css('background-color', 'transparent');
                    $("nav a").css('color', '#fafafa');
                    $('nav span').css('color','#fafafa');
                    $("nav").removeClass("hidden").addClass("visible");
                    $("nav a").removeClass("hidden").addClass("visible");
                    $("nav span").removeClass("hidden").addClass("visible");
                }}





                if(($(window).width() >= 1020 && scroll_pos > 45)) {
                    $("nav").removeClass("visible").addClass("hidden");
                    $("nav a").removeClass("visible").addClass("hidden");
                    $("nav span").removeClass("visible").addClass("hidden");

                } 
                if(($(window).width() >= 1020 && scroll_pos > 650)) {
                    $("nav").removeClass("hidden").addClass("visible");
                    $("nav a").removeClass("hidden").addClass("visible");
                    $("nav span").removeClass("hidden").addClass("visible");
                    $("nav").css('background-color', '#fafafa');

                    $("nav a").css('color', '#404040');
                    $('nav span').css('color','#404040');
                }
                else {
                    $("nav").css('background-color', 'transparent');
                    $("nav a").css('color', '#fafafa');
                    $("nav span").css('color', '#fafafa');
                }
                if(($(window).width() >= 1020 && scroll_pos > 1220)) {
                    $("nav a").css('color', '#33adff');
                    $("nav span").css('color', '#33adff');
                }
                if(($(window).width() >= 1020 && scroll_pos > 1245)) {
                    $("nav").css('background-color', '#fafafa');
                }

                if(($(window).width() >= 1020 && scroll_pos < 45)) {
                    $("nav").css('background-color', 'transparent');
                    $("nav a").css('color', '#fafafa');
                    $('nav span').css('color','#fafafa');
                    $("nav").removeClass("hidden").addClass("visible");
                    $("nav a").removeClass("hidden").addClass("visible");
                    $("nav span").removeClass("hidden").addClass("visible");
                }




                {if(($(window).width() >= 750 && scroll_pos > 40)) {
                    $("nav").removeClass("visible").addClass("hidden");
                    $("nav a").removeClass("visible").addClass("hidden");
                    $("nav span").removeClass("visible").addClass("hidden");

                } 
                if(($(window).width() >= 750 && scroll_pos > 620)) {
                    $("nav").removeClass("hidden").addClass("visible");
                    $("nav a").removeClass("hidden").addClass("visible");
                    $("nav span").removeClass("hidden").addClass("visible");
                    $("nav").css('background-color', '#fafafa');

                    $("nav a").css('color', '#404040');
                    $('nav span').css('color','#404040');
                }
                else {
                    $("nav").css('background-color', 'transparent');
                    $("nav a").css('color', '#fafafa');
                    $("nav span").css('color', '#fafafa');
                }
                if(($(window).width() >= 750 && scroll_pos > 1200)) {
                    $("nav a").css('color', '#33adff');
                    $("nav span").css('color', '#33adff');
                }
                if(($(window).width() >= 750 && scroll_pos > 1220)) {
                    $("nav").css('background-color', '#fafafa');
                }

                if(($(window).width() >= 750 && scroll_pos < 40)) {
                    $("nav").css('background-color', 'transparent');
                    $("nav a").css('color', '#fafafa');
                    $('nav span').css('color','#fafafa');
                    $("nav").removeClass("hidden").addClass("visible");
                    $("nav a").removeClass("hidden").addClass("visible");
                    $("nav span").removeClass("hidden").addClass("visible");
                }}
            });
        });
        ```
````

Comment: I suggest storing `$(window).width()` in  a variable as all is executed at the same moment

Comment: Forgive me, how would you make a variable out of a jQuery selector?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a bit of a hard time trying to understand what intervals you wanted so I put some comments to help you achieve what you wanted if it doesn't as it is.
Furthermore, I have combined the ifs structures in order not to reevaluate an expression uselessly.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    var scroll_pos = 0;

    $(document).scroll(function () {
        scroll_pos = $(this).scrollTop();
        var width = $(window).width();


        if (width >= 1350) {

            // ALL WHAT FOLLOW IMPLIES THAT width >= 1350

            // (1) : This overrides (2) because 
            if (scroll_pos <= 50) { // Range [0,50]
                $("nav").css('background-color', 'transparent');
                $("nav a").css('color', '#fafafa');
                $('nav span').css('color', '#fafafa');
                $("nav").removeClass("hidden").addClass("visible");
                $("nav a").removeClass("hidden").addClass("visible");
                $("nav span").removeClass("hidden").addClass("visible");
            }


            if (scroll_pos > 50) { // RANGE [50,+∝]

                $("nav").removeClass("visible").addClass("hidden");
                $("nav a").removeClass("visible").addClass("hidden");
                $("nav span").removeClass("visible").addClass("hidden");
            }

            if (scroll_pos > 690) { // [689,∝]
                $("nav").removeClass("hidden").addClass("visible");
                $("nav a").removeClass("hidden").addClass("visible");
                $("nav span").removeClass("hidden").addClass("visible");
                $("nav").css('background-color', '#fafafa');

                $("nav a").css('color', '#404040');
                $('nav span').css('color', '#404040');
            }

            /** 
             * 
             * (2)
             * THIS IS NEVER "VISIBILY EXECUTED"  : SEE (1)
             * 
             * YOU HAVE WRITTEN :

            else {
                $("nav").css('background-color', 'transparent');
                $("nav a").css('color', '#fafafa');
                $("nav span").css('color', '#fafafa');
            }

            **/

            if (scroll_pos > 1270) { // [1270,+∝]
                $("nav a").css('color', '#33adff');
                $("nav span").css('color', '#33adff');
            }

            /**
             * 
             * NOTE THAT IF SCROLL_POS > 1970 EVERYTHING ABOVE WOULD BE EXECUTED SO YOU WOULD HAVE A COMBINATION 
             * THIS IS BECAUSE 1970 > 690 > 50 SO EVERYTHING ABOVE IS TRUE
             * IF YOU WANT TO MAKE CLOSED INTERVALS PLEASE TRY PUTTING THE HIGHEST VALUE OF scroll_pos AT BEGINNING AND USING ELSE IF
             */

        }



        if (width >= 1020) {

            if (scroll_pos >= 45) {
                $("nav").removeClass("visible").addClass("hidden");
                $("nav a").removeClass("visible").addClass("hidden");
                $("nav span").removeClass("visible").addClass("hidden");
            }

            if (scroll_pos > 650) {
                $("nav").removeClass("hidden").addClass("visible");
                $("nav a").removeClass("hidden").addClass("visible");
                $("nav span").removeClass("hidden").addClass("visible");
                $("nav").css('background-color', '#fafafa');

                $("nav a").css('color', '#404040');
                $('nav span').css('color', '#404040');
            } else { // RANGE [0,620]
                $("nav").css('background-color', 'transparent');
                $("nav a").css('color', '#fafafa');
                $("nav span").css('color', '#fafafa');
            }

            if (scroll_pos > 1220) {
                $("nav a").css('color', '#33adff');
                $("nav span").css('color', '#33adff');
            }
            if (scroll_pos > 1245) {
                $("nav").css('background-color', '#fafafa');
            }

            if (scroll_pos < 45) {
                $("nav").css('background-color', 'transparent');
                $("nav a").css('color', '#fafafa');
                $('nav span').css('color', '#fafafa');
                $("nav").removeClass("hidden").addClass("visible");
                $("nav a").removeClass("hidden").addClass("visible");
                $("nav span").removeClass("hidden").addClass("visible");
            }

        }

        if (width >= 750) {
            if (scroll_pos > 40) {
                $("nav").removeClass("visible").addClass("hidden");
                $("nav a").removeClass("visible").addClass("hidden");
                $("nav span").removeClass("visible").addClass("hidden");

            }

            if (scroll_pos > 620) {
                $("nav").removeClass("hidden").addClass("visible");
                $("nav a").removeClass("hidden").addClass("visible");
                $("nav span").removeClass("hidden").addClass("visible");
                $("nav").css('background-color', '#fafafa');

                $("nav a").css('color', '#404040');
                $('nav span').css('color', '#404040');
            } else { // RANGE [0,620]
                $("nav").css('background-color', 'transparent');
                $("nav a").css('color', '#fafafa');
                $("nav span").css('color', '#fafafa');
            }
            if (scroll_pos > 1200) {
                $("nav a").css('color', '#33adff');
                $("nav span").css('color', '#33adff');
            }
            if (scroll_pos > 1220) {
                $("nav").css('background-color', '#fafafa');
            }

            if (scroll_pos < 40) {
                $("nav").css('background-color', 'transparent');
                $("nav a").css('color', '#fafafa');
                $('nav span').css('color', '#fafafa');
                $("nav").removeClass("hidden").addClass("visible");
                $("nav a").removeClass("hidden").addClass("visible");
                $("nav span").removeClass("hidden").addClass("visible");
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: You're an absolute star, I'll start through this now. Thank you